# How do I dynamically change ubercart's default messages from my module

Tags: drupal, ubercart

There are some products for which I would like to have a special checkout complete message that would differ from the default.

I know that I could probably do this by **changing the default redirect page** to something else.  *[And I'm not sure if that would introduce another problem]*

However, I would like to know if there is a **standard/better way** of approaching this problem.

Thanks!,

D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the [String Overrides](https://www.drupal.org/project/stringoverrides) module. Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> Provides a quick and easy way to replace any text on the site.
>
> Features:
>
> - Easily replace anything that's passed through [t()](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/t)
> - Locale support, allowing you to override strings in any language
> - Ability to import/export *.po files, for easy migration from the Locale module
> - Note that this is not a replacement to Locale as having thousands of overrides can cause more pain then benefit. Use this only if you need a few easy text changes.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the only other possible way of doing what I am thinking of is to **override the theme function** that ubercart uses to display the message.  And this probably seems like it would make the most sense.

In this case I would override **theme_uc_cart_complete_sale**

I could set a

```
$_SESSION['is_special_product'] == TRUE;
```

and then set $message to my $special_message if it's been set.

```
if ($_SESSION['special_product']) {
      $special_message = t('This is my special message');
      $message = variable_get('special_product_message', $special_message;
    }
```

Finally, to override from my module I will need to hook into the pre-process hook:

```
function $modulename_prepocess_$hook(&$message) {
      if ($_SESSION['special_product']) {
      $special_message = t('This is my special message');
      $message = variable_get('special_product_message', $special_message;
    }
}
```

It is important to note that **it is not enough to have this function in your module**.  The preprocess functions are only invoked when the template file that overrides the theme function is called.

More details can be found at http://drupal.org/node/223430